# Foreign key with one to many relations

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am using EF Core v5.0.2 and a SQL Server database.

I set the foreign key in two tables.

Primary key: Student.cs

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Foreign key: StudentAddress.cs

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public int StudentId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("StudentId")]
public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
```

Second foreign key: StudentDetail.cs

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public int StudentId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("StudentId")]
public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
```

The `DbContext` file:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StudentAddress> StudentAddress { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StudentDetail> StudentDetail { get; set; }
}
```

I get this error :

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ Student Address_Student_StudentId". The conflict occurred in database "StudData", table "dbo.Student", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.

[image]

Comment: Do you have already a Student for the Address you are trying to insert?

Comment: I got the solution...
The primary key (Student) you enter in the foreign key table (StudentId) should have the student's data in the primary key (empty field does not allow in primary key)